# Why is Visual Studio replacing List<T>.Length with List<T>.Count?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I've noticed that if have a `List<T>` (or a few other types) and I press `.` then among the intellisense suggestions I get `Length`

[image]

If I select `Length` then what's actually typed is `Count`

[image]

I can see why this would happen, there's no `Length` property on a `List<T>` and if I'm looking for it I probably want `Count`. My question is, how does Visual Studio know to do this? I can't see anything in the `List<T>` class or anywhere else that encodes `Length` as an alias for `Count`.

Comment: Well, perhaps it tries to foresee and preventively correct a typical mistake?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a ReSharper 10 feature.

It integrated the [Postfix Templates plugin](https://github.com/controlflow/resharper-postfix) in this version, and this is one of the completions it supports (use the correct `Length` or `Count` property).

> I'm excited to announce that this plugin is now integral part of ReSharper 10!

The project page states:

> **Length/Count** code completion solves one of the most common mistypings when dealing with arrays or collections:
>
> [image: example]